# Wrap figure changes right spacing

Tags: moderncv, wrapfigure

I'm using moderncv and I'd like to add a note at the end of last page.
I added it using `\vspace` but somehow this sentence has huge right spacing, as you can see from the picture here.

In my document I also have a logo, and after some tries I realized that it is because of this wrap figure that I have the issue. Removing the picture the note at the bottom of the page has normal spacing. It is quite weird because only that sentence is influenced and not the test of the text.

How can I fix this? Here there are the output example and a MWE

Output example:
[image: output example]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{John} % Your first name
\familyname{Smith} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{123 Broadway}{City, State 12345}
\mobile{(000) 111 1111}
\fax{(000) 111 1113}
\email{john@smith.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\quote{"A witty and playful quotation" - John Smith}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle % Print the CV title


%% LOGO  ---------------------------------------------------------
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.20\textwidth}
    \vspace{-70pt}
    \begin{center}
    \textit{This is my special logo}
        \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{pictures/logo}
    \textit{my logo}
    \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
%% ------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Contact Information}

\cvitem{Mobile 1}{012 345 6789}
\cvitem{Mobile 1}{012 345 6789}
\cvitem{E-mail}{email@email.com}

\section{Education}

\cventry{2011--2012}{Masters of Commerce}{The University of California}{Berkeley}{\textit{GPA -- 8.0}}{First Class Honours}  % Arguments not required can be left empty
\cventry{2007--2010}{Bachelor of Business Studies}{The University of California}{Berkeley}{\textit{GPA -- 7.5}}{Specialized in Commerce}

\section{Masters Thesis}

\cvitem{Title}{\emph{Money Is The Root Of All Evil -- Or Is It?}}
\cvitem{Supervisors}{Professor James Smith \& Associate Professor Jane Smith}
\cvitem{Description}{This thesis explored the idea that money has been the cause of untold anguish and suffering in the world. I found that it has, in fact, not.}

\section{Custom}
\cvitem{AA}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit eleifend feugiat mauris}
\cvitem{BB}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit eleifend feugiat mauris}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CLOSING SENTENCE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\vspace{\stretch{1}}\textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras fringilla ligula sit amet est dignissim commodo. Integer eleifend feugiat mauris et congue. Aenean eget sem leo.}
\begin{flushright}
\textit{Last update: Feb 2016} 
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using `\centering` instead of `begin{center}` and `end{center}` and adding `\vspace{-82pt}` before `\end{wrapfigure}`.

If you have a better solution, please post it.